# Verify working of I2C bus though command

Tags: linux, i2c, archlinux, arm

I am trying to verify I2C bus through command (`i2c tools`) only. For this purpose I detect my I2C buses as follows

```
ls -l /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c*
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan 27 12:33 /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-0 -> ../../../devices/platform/ocp/44e0b000.i2c/i2c-0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan 27 12:33 /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-2 -> ../../../devices/platform/ocp/4819c000.i2c/i2c-2
```

For the first I2C

```
i2cdetect -y -r 0
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 2d -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Similarly for other one

```
i2cdetect -y -r 2
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: UU UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

For writing something on the I2C bus trying to write 2 bytes at address 0x77

```
i2cset -y 0 0x77 0xf4 0x34                                                                                                          
Error: Write failed
```

Similarly for other one

```
i2cset -y 2 0x77 0xf4 0x34
Error: Write failed
```

Read is been done by

```
i2cget
```

But not getting the result as expected. Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The Raspberry Pi does do not have an I2C bus 2, it has an I2C bus 0 and an I2C bus 1.

Are you using a Raspberry Pi?

You can't write to an I2C device which doesn't exist.  There is no evidence that a device exists at address 0x77.  That is why the write fails.